# Quote from mathematician-poet

Tags: reference-request

I read once a quote by a mathematician (or scientist) who was also a poet and it was something similar to:

> As a mathematician I try to make complicated things obvious, as a poet I try to make obvious things complicated,

but I can't find it online or remember who said it. Does anyone know? Or if you know a similar quote I would really appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: It rings a bell,but I can't place it. But if you like poet-mathematicians, check out [Piet Hein](http://www.sophilos.net/GrooksofPietHein.htm).

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is on topic

Comment: I'm not sure that "make obvious things complicated" is a good description of what a poet does. Perhaps "make obvious things strange" would be better.

Comment: Am I the only one who feels like mathematicians have a habit of making simple concepts insanely complicated? (not saying they don't have their reasons for it, but that's beside my point)

Answer (score 30):

Also, a similar quote is attributed to Paul Dirac (criticising Oppenheimer's interest in poetry):

> "The aim of science is to make difficult things understandable in a
>   simpler way; the aim of poetry is to state simple things in an
>   incomprehensible way. The two are incompatible."

Comment: citation needed?

Comment: @LarsH, see [page 258 of Dirac's biography](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zXm1Bso1VREC&pg=PA258&lpg=PA258&dq=%22The+aim+of+science+is+to+make+difficult+things+understandable+in+a+simpler+way;+the+aim+of+poetry+is+to+state+simple+things+in+an+incomprehensible+way.+The+two+are+incompatible%22&source=bl&ots=OLeGFpZGCh&sig=VRga1I7FVl9UBpXi_oAq_-8u_ls&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBwLbbwdvVAhXIIMAKHZ_pCZQQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage)

Comment: @sch But what is the biography's source?

Answer (score 16):

You are probably thinking of J. Robert Oppenheimer quoting Paul Dirac in the first paragraph of an article entitled "[The Age of Science 1900-1950](https://doi.org/10.1038/scientificamerican0950-20)", published in the September 1950 issue:

> One evening more than 20 years ago Dirac, who was in Göttingen working on his
> quantum theory of radiation, took me to task with characteristic gentleness.
> "I understand," he said, "that you are writing poetry as well as working at
> physics. I do not see how you can do both. In science one tries to say some­
> thing that no one knew before in a way that everyone can understand. Whereas
> in poetry ..."
>
> The 10 reports here, to which these words may serve as introduction, do
> indeed attest that science says things that no one knew before in a way we
> can all understand.

Oppenheimer had published poems in the Harvard student literary magazine *Hound & Horn*, including one from 1928 called "[Crossing](https://web.archive.org/web/20190908124907/http://thebatterseareview.com/critical-prose/85-back-issue-content/114-j-r-oppenheimer)" inspired by his time in the desert of New Mexico.

Comment: note also Hilbert on math vs poetry: Good, he did not have enough imagination to become a mathematician.Upon hearing that one of his students had dropped out to study poetry, as quoted in [http://books.google.com/?id=nnpChqstvg0C&pg=PA151 The Universal Book of Mathematics (2004) by David J. Darling, p. 151

Answer (score 14):

A similar quote is usually attributed to the mathematician Stan Gudder (U. of Denver):

*"The essence of mathematics is not to make simple things complicated, but to make complicated things simple."*

Answer (score 2):

Also a quote is attributed to **Sofia Kovalevskaya**:

> *It is impossible to be a mathematician without being a poet in soul.”* — Sofia Kovalevskaya

Also this article [Mathematicians and Poets](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjTk8Xh_vXXAhUp6oMKHbOeBDgQFgh0MAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fnotices%2F201104%2Frtx110400590p.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3y307nxN78_oe982oWPJ2p) is very intersting.